# Is the Win32_Processor and Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI methods available in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am testing an existing application in the Windows 8 consumer preview and it crashes upon launching.  The log files indicate it is in the method where I do some validation on the CPU ID and Network card details.

To do this, I am calling

```
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (cpuInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                // only return cpuInfo from first CPU
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["ProcessorId"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

(Note that this application works fine on Windows 7 and earlier).

I then use the same syntax for hooking into Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration and getting the IPEnabled, IPAddress[], and MACAddress properties.

But somewhere in here it is crashing.

I have tried to research this already, and found the following [Windows 8 server list of WMI classes and methods](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-8-server-wmi-classes-with-methods.aspx) and the ones I am using are not on it.  However, the same site has a list of [Windows 7 WMI classes and methods](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-7-wmi-classes-with-methods.aspx) too, and these aren't in that either! (Even though it works on Windows 7 no problem).

So from the look of that, it is not supported.

The MSDN for the ManagementClass indicates that the method [is still present in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s54685%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Additionally, [this Microsoft resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does explicitly list Win32_Processor and Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration, with the methods I need.

So, from the links, you can see I have tried to research this, so this is my last stop in trying to solve this mystery.

My app is originally a .NET 2.0 solution created in Visual Studio 2005.  I have installed Visual Studio 2011 Beta into my Windows 8 Consumer Preview VM, along with the latest SQL 2012 Express.  I have tried importing my project into this Visual Studio but it doesn't load it, telling me that it only supports Metro development.  Therefore I cannot debug this issue on the machine itself.

So my question is specifically do these classes exist in Windows 8?  If they do, then what am I doing wrong?  If they don't, then I need to find out a way to still get this information - but I guess that's a separate question ;-)

Comment: I can't believe they would remove them, quick way to test; download WMICC and use its GUI to see if they are listed/ what you expect http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572

Comment: Side note: Visual Studio 2011? There's [no such thing](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Visual-Studio-11-Not-2011.aspx), not even in Beta. There's a Version 11 beta available at the moment, but no final product name has been announced. High chance of it being named 2012 though.

Comment: Hi thanks, I used the WMICC and indeed it is there!  I think though it may have helped as the Processor ID it retrieved was blank.  Perhaps due to me running in a VM?  As for VS 2011/11 naming I apologise - its whatever you get at www.microsoft.com/express that is for Windows 8 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered but unfortunately only in comments on my original post, by Alex K.  Using http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572 I was able to identify these methods do exist, so I figure it's a coding issue as my code is slightly different to what is generated by that utility.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm which both WMI classes (Win32_Processor and Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration) exist and works under in Windows 8 Developer Preview.

**FYI the list which your refear has the title [`Windows 8 Server WMI Classes with Methods`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-8-server-wmi-classes-with-methods.aspx), which means `WMI Classes which had methods.`**

[image]

[image]

Tool used to check [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)

Answer (score 0):

The WMI methods were available in Windows 8, but were removed in Windows 8.1, so alternatively, you could use this code to analyze various network metrics on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/network-information-sample-63aaa201